# subprocess grab stdout of airodump-ng

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to grab the stdout from airodump-ng using subprocess with no luck.
I think my code causes a deadlock.

```
   airodump = subprocess.Popen(['airodump-ng','mon0'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    # wait for 15 seconds to find all networks
    time.sleep(15)

    # save the output
    o_airodump = airodump.stdout.read()
    os.kill(airodump.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
    # airodump.terminate
    print(o_airodump)
```

How to avoid this problem. Cant think one clean solution.

Comment: Why is stdin marked as a pipe? That might be causing problems.

Comment: stdin being a pipe won't matter, airodump-ng isn't expecting any input.  The hang is caused by two things that my answer below addresses: The child processes can blocking due to filling up its output pipe buffers which aren't being read if it generates enough output *and* the unbounded read() call is not going to return until the process dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sleep and wait (that will just cause airodump to block on a full pipe buffer) and don't use an unbounded read().  The communicate() method does what you need:

```
o_airodump, unused_stderr = airodump.communicate(timeout=15)
airodump.kill()
```

Note: The timeout parameter on communicate was introduced in Python 3.3 which isn't *quite* out yet. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew I was in the wrong direction.
Does `timeout` need a special import? cause I get an error.
I am using python3 if this makes a difference.

Comment: Updated to mention that, yes, timeout is new in Python 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

```
airodump.communicate()
```

waits for the process to terminate then returns `(stdout, stderr)`

IF you really pushed you could always link directly to the c library using ctypes. Enjoy hacking.